# Redemption and it's RDOAppointmentItem, start and end times for an appointment, resulting in different days in Outlook Mobile App

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

Using the Interop.Redemption dll (version  5.20.0.5298)
We sync appointments between our .net application and Outlook using an addin.
When I create an All-Day event in my .net application we sync it across as an appointment item of type: "RDOAppointmentItem"

This RDO Appt when viewed on Outlook desktop application is correct, showing up as an All Day event from 12am day of to 12am the day after.

When using the Outlook mobile app on Android (all I can test with), this RDO Appt when synced across to the mobile app will show up as ranging from the day before to the day after.

I've narrowed down the problem to be that the mobile app is using UTC time as its start and end, this was done by offsetting the start time ahead by 10 hours (as I am GMT+10)

However this problem only becomes apparent when using an RDOAppointmentItem, if I change my logic to use the Outlook Interop standard "AppointmentItem" and save that, when it syncs across to the Outlook Mobile App, the all day event goes from 12am day of to 12am the day after, i.e. everything works correctly.

The StartUTC and EndUTC are set correctly and I've tried using OutlookSpy to check the MAPI properties and everything appears to be the same (Start/End/Timezone wise) on the 2 appointments in Outlook desktop

Using AppointmentItem

```cs
    var apptItem = folder.Items.Add(OlItemType.olAppointmentItem) as AppointmentItem;
    apptItem.AllDayEvent = dotnetAppt.AllDay;
    apptItem.StartUTC = dotnetAppt.StartTime;
    apptItem.EndUTC = dotnetAppt.EndTime;
    apptItem.Subject = dotnetAppt.Subject;
    apptItem.Save();
```

Using RDOAppointmentItem

```cs
    outlookCalendarFolder = rdoSession.GetFolderFromID(_syncSettings.CalendarEntryId))
    rdoAppointment = outlookCalendarFolder.Items.Add(OlItemType.olAppointmentItem) as RDOAppointmentItem;
    rdoAppointment.AllDayEvent = dotnetAppt.AllDay;
    rdoAppointment.StartUTC = dotnetAppt.StartTime;
    rdoAppointment.EndUTC = dotnetAppt.EndTime;
    rdoAppointment.Subject = dotnetAppt.Subject;
    rdoAppointment.Save();
```

Is there something special that the RDOAppointmentItem is doing in its Start, End, StartUTC, EndUTC, TimeZone or any other possible date related item properties?

I can't quite think of any other explanation.

Edit: Here is the props that are present on the olAppointmentItem and are absent from RDOAppointmentItem
[image: olAppointmentItem]

Here is the props that are on the RDOAppointmentItem that are absent from the olAppointmentItem

[image: rdoAppointmentItem]

Here are the descriptions of the two properties I thought might be most relevant that are on the olAppointmentItem but not on the RDOAppointmentItem

[image: start timezone]

[image: end timezone]

Hopefully that helps

Comment: Have you tried to compare the good and the bad appointments in Outlook Spy (click IMessage | Compare tab)?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I've edited my question above to have the results of comparison

Comment: Can you try to drag one or two properties from the good appointment to the bad one and see if the sync picks up the appointment correctly?

Comment: Hi @DmitryStreblechenko I've dragged across the two properties of "AppointmentTimeZoneDefinitionStartDisplay" and "AppointmentTimeZoneDefinitionEndDisplay" to the bad appointment and is syncing correctly now to outlook mobile. 



Is this an issue to be fixed in redemption or should I be setting it with the DASL?

If setting it with DASL, what value should I be providing?

Comment: please send en email to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com and i will send you the updated version of Redemption.